# How can I pass values inside Factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

For every `User` factory I need to create a nested `Photo` loading an image from disk. I'm wondering how could I simplify this code by simply declaring the file name as an attribute of the user factory.

This code also has a problem, is saving :women factory file name as `avatar1.jpg` instead of `avatar2.jpg`, probably because of the first User after.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'john@site.com'
    country 'US'

    after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
      photo_file = 'avatar1.jpg'
      photo_object = File.new(File.join(::Rails.root.to_s, "/factories/images", photo_file), 'rb')
      user.photos << FactoryGirl.build(:photo, photo: photo_object, user: user)
      user.avatar_id = user.photos.first.id
      user.save
    end

    factory :woman do
      email 'annie@site'
      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        photo_file = 'avatar2.jpg'
        photo_object = File.new(File.join(::Rails.root.to_s, "/factories/images", photo_file), 'rb')
        user.photos << FactoryGirl.build(:photo, photo: photo_object, user: user)
        user.avatar_id = user.photos.first.id
        user.save
      end
    end

  end
end
```

This is the model relationship

```
# user.rb
has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

# photo.rb
belongs_to :user
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion on how to organize your code better, you should move file reading logic into the `Photo` model itself. For example:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :filename

  after_initialize do |p|
    if filename
      p.photo = File.new(File.join(::Rails.root.to_s, filename), 'rb')
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use [traits](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits) to create male and female users, using `create(:user, :male)` and `create(:user, :female)` as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    country 'US'

    ignore { photo_count 1 }    # ignored attribute - number of photos to build per user

    trait :male do
      email 'john@site.com'

      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:photo, evaluator.photo_count, :male, user: user)
      end
    end

    trait :female do
      email 'annie@site.com'

      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:photo, evaluator.photo_count, :female, user: user)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :photo do
    trait :male do
      filename '/factories/images/avatar1.jpg'
    end

    trait :female do
      filename '/factories/images/avatar2.jpg'
    end

    user # the user to be associated with the photo
  end
end
```

Comment: Mmm. I get a `syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    trait :male { filename '/factories/images/avatar1.jpg' }
                 ^` error.

Comment: Strange...try changing the block to long form as I updated above.

Comment: I still get `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Photo file name can't be blank, User can't be blank`. Looks like for some reason its not considering the `after_initialize` nor the `association itself.` I have updated my question with the model relationship, which is very simple and its working outside the scope of FactoryGirl..

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that `photos` is a collection association. In the update above, the `create_list` method is used to create a photo for the user (male or female), with the appropriate trait, which determines the filename, and the user record. The latter should fix the blank user error, but `filename` shouldn't be coming up blank.

Comment: I still get a `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Photo file name can't be blank`. `Photo` model `validates_presence_of :photo_file_name` but the file name should be saved when the Photo object is created which is not. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an elegant solution but a quick fix would be to make

```
user.avatar_id = user.photos.last.id
```